# Как авторизоваться в вк с помощью requests? Python

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, requests

Вот код:

```
import requests

r = requests.get("https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=1&redirect_url=friend").json()

print(r)
```

```
 {'error': 'invalid_request', 'error_description': 'OAuth authorization cannot be used from native VK applications'}
```

Что надо добавить чтобы авторизоваться в вк?

Comment: Понимаю, что советую очевидное, но вы не рассматривали [vk api](https://pypi.org/project/vk-api/)?

Comment: Смотрите, есть гуи приложение, в нем два инпута, первый логин а второй пароль, надо что бы пользователь ввёл логин и пароль и получил свой accest token